# Most concise way to check if multiple variables are between the same limits

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have three variables, `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I want to perform a check whether all three of them are inside the limits `A` and `B`. I'm looking for the most concise and pythonic way to do so. I know that I can check *one* variable as

```
if A < x < B:
   [some code here]
```

However, for three variables the shortest I could come up with without the help of something like `numpy` is

```
if (A < x < B) and (A < y < B) and (A < z < B):
   [some code here]
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`all()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp).

e.g.

```
if all(A < n < B for n in (x, y, z)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

store them and `list` and use `all`

```
lst = [x,y,z]

if all(A<i<B for i in lst):
    # your code
    # print(True)
```